# Certain objects within a for loop are not iterating through

Tags: python

I am trying to run through a for look and I am running into issues when I get a certain way through the code. I am running the following portion of my code:

```
for f in adg1:
    sptline2 = f.split(' ') #delimits line using a space
    sptline3 = list(filter(None, sptline2))
```

Currently, It runs through the sptline2 portion and sptline2 returns an output when I print it. However, when I get to the sptline3, nothing is being returned as sptline3. When I type the same code into where I can call the function, sptline3 is assigned a value, but when it is being run in the code, it returns an empty list.

This isn't the whole code, so there might be some things missing from this section that may help and I can add those as needed. The relevant section of the code that I am having issues with is below:

```
for f in adg1:
     sptline2 = f.split(' ') #delimits line using a space
     sptline3 = list(filter(None, sptline2)) #removes empty values
     for x in sptline3:
     if sptline3.index(x) == len(sptline)-1: #gets last value
         adgvals.append(x) #adds adg values into list 
         for ad in adgvals:
             ad1 = ad.strip('"')
             ad2 = ad1.replace('444.000\n', '444.0')
             ad3 = ad2.strip('\n')
             adgvals2.append(ad3)
```

A sample of adg1 is the following:

```
[ '   8903  31 2310   1.378\n', '   8903  31 2320   1.378\n', '   8903  31 2330 444.000\n', '   8903  31 2340 444.000\n', '   8903  31 2350   1.378\n']
```

A sample output of sptline2 is as follows:

```
['', '', '', '8903', '', '31', '2350', '', '', '1.378\n']
```

The errors I am receiving are regarding looping through the empty list and trying to add the new  (nonexistent) values.

```
print(sptline3)
[]
```

I am expecting to get the following for sptline3:

```
['8903','31', '2350', '1.378\n']
```

And eventually expecting to get a list of all of the values from the last column of each sptline3 for the output of adgvals2:

```
['1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.377\n']
```

Please let me know if you have questions and thank you!

Comment: What is `adg1`?

Comment: @S3DEV It is a read in text file using this: adg1 = adg.readlines()

Comment: Sorry, I’ll rephrase: What is the content of your text file, and thus `adg1`?

Comment: @S3DEV Oh, sorry - I just tried to add some of it... Did the edits that I made clarify this?

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Can you also please show your expected result?  Thanks!

Comment: @S3DEV Done, please let me know if I should add anything else! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your issue is from your if statement it should be

```
for f in adg1:
sptline2 = f.split(' ')
sptline3 = list(filter(None, sptline2))
for x in sptline3:
    if sptline3.index(x) >= len(sptline3)-1:
```

your condition is not true that is why it is returning noting, 
you should compare with len of sptline3 not sptline

And there is still an error in your code aside that, what you did will give duplicate the end result, either by 3 or more.. but this will give you the expected result

```
adg1 = [ '   8903  31 2310   1.378\n', '   8903  31 2320   1.378\n', '   8903  31 2330 444.000\n', '   8903  31 2340 444.000\n', '   8903  31 2350   1.378\n']
adgvals = []
adgvals1 = []
for f in adg1:
sptline2 = f.split(' ')
sptline3 = list(filter(None, sptline2))
for x in sptline3:
    if sptline3.index(x) >= len(sptline3)-1:
        adgvals.append(x)
        if len(adgvals) == len(adg1):
            for ad in adgvals:
                ad1 = ad.strip('\n')
                ad2 = ad1.replace( '444.000\n', '440')
                adgvals1.append(ad2)
```

there are shorter means of achieving this true but this follow your initial pattern

Comment: I just updated with the expected outputs... Does this help?

Comment: are you printing immediately after your for loop?

Comment: Yes. I get an empty list just like the sptline3 output above.

Comment: and i dont get that last part:                                                                           And eventually expecting to get a list of all of the values from the last column of each sptline3 for the output of adgvals2:

 ['1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.378\n', '1.377\n']

Comment: So the last part where I am appending to adgvals2, I am expecting to get the ['1.378\n', '1.378\'] as the output, but since sptline3 is empty I am getting an empty list.

Comment: check the answer now, and its like you have a variable 'sptline' that's why it didnt show error